sed/vim newline search and replace
I'd like to search for lines that have fudge and place them at the end of the previous line.
Could someone explain to me why the following works in vim but not with sed? (i.e. if I open the file called test with vim and key in %s/\(.*\)\n\(fudge\)/\1  \2/g it does what I want it to).
echo -e 'foo bar baz\nfudge' > test
sed -e 's/\(.*\)\n\(fudge\)/\1  \2/g' test


Your command can't work because sed is strictly line-based. It only sees the line foo bar baz or the line fudge when executing the command so your pattern doesn't match and nothing happens. See this answer for a possible workaround and the rest of the thread for more appropriate tools.

sed reads the input 1 line at a time by default so there is no newline in the default single-line buffer that sed is working on at any given time, but you can used GNU sed for -z to instead read the whole file into memory at once:
$ printf 'foo bar baz\nfudge\n' > file

$ sed -Ez 's/(.*)\n(fudge)/\1  \2/' file
foo bar baz  fudge

I added -E to enable EREs just to reduce the escaping.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n(.*fudge)/ \1/;ta;P;D' file

Open a two line window throughout the length of the file and if the second line contains fudge, append that line to the first and go again.
N.B. If two consecutive lines could contain fudge but only the first of these is to be joined with the previous line, use:
sed -E 'N;s/\n(.*fudge)/ \1/;P;D' file

